# Volume of a cylinder on a slope

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

A cylindrical water tank which is 35 feet in diameter and 105 feet in length is placed temporarily on an 18.5 degree slope. The filler is located flush with the top of the tank at midpoint. What is the maximum volume of water which can be placed in the tank?

The answer is 90,343.92 cubic ft but I'm getting 95,388 cubic ft after solving for the unoccupied space and subtracting it from the volume of the cylinder. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What does "flush with the top of the tank at midpoint" mean?

Comment: I think it means it just touches the top at midpoint? I'm not really sure though...

Answer (score 1):

First, I found exactly the same result as yours.
The trick is that the cylinder is not fully open on top of it.

The gray part is the missing one. Try with it :)

[image: the gray part is the missing one...]

Comment: Wouldn't that make the volume bigger than 95,388? I solved for that diagram and got 99,613.45 cubic feet.